# TypeError: superagent.auth is not a function, x is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, superagent

im literally just following the code on this site but I am having this error, not sure why

https://developers.telnyx.com/docs/v2/messaging/twexit?lang=python&fbclid=IwAR08WBnG4cLSbcRVneMpui0V02W90oCAExCbNb6ICJrQa6dgkkv_kzxsA-o

```
// https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#install
const superagent = require('superagent');

superagent
  .auth('my strings')
  .post(`https://api.telnyx.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my string/Messages.json`)
  .send({
    From: '', // Your Telnyx number
    To: '',
    Body: "Is this working, World!"
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.body);
  });
```

note: i just wrote my strings in place of the actual code for privacy

Answer (score 0):

method comes first, reverse it: `...post().auth()...`:

```
// https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent#install
const superagent = require('superagent');

superagent
  .post(`https://api.telnyx.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/my string/Messages.json`)
  .auth('my strings')
  .send({
    From: '', // Your Telnyx number
    To: '',
    Body: "Is this working, World!"
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.body);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you! I actually got a response back after running it, why wouldn't they update the code on the site if its post before auth??? god